# Implement the add-and-shift algorithm for multiplication in C

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the add-and-shift algorithm for multiplication in C but my code does not seem to be working properly. When I input a=35, b=19 the code returns 0.  When I input a=-35, b=-19 the code overflows. Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

```
void main(){
    int a, b, c;
    printf("Enter an integer: \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter an integer: \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    //multiply(a, b);

    c = 0; //product

    while(b != 0)
    {
        if(b & '\x01' == 1)
        {
            c = c + a;
        }
        a = a << 1;
        b = b >> 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing a bitwise and with a character literal?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg This looks bad, but should work. The value is `1` anyway.

Comment: To help you find your problem, there's a tool that you should use, it's called a "debugger". With it you can step through the code, line by line, while seeing the values of variables.

Comment: Hint: `printf ("%d\n", (-1 >> 1));` and `printf ("-%u\n", (1U >> 1));`

Comment: Er... you do know, that `b & '\x01' == 1` is evaluated like `b & ('\x01' == 1)`? Doesn't make a difference here, though...

Comment: @mafso But funny enough, it still works _in our case_.

Comment: This code does not return anything or output anything

Answer (score 3):

> When I input a=35, b=19 the code returns 0

It works for me and gives the expected `665`.

---

> When I input a=-35, b=-19 the code overflows

This algorithm is not supposed to work with negative numbers. Shifting negative values is undefined for `<< 1` and implementation-defined for `>> 1`.

In my case (Visual studio) b stays `-1` and the loop never ends. And

```
int i = -1;
printf("%d\n", i >> 1);
```

prints `-1`.

Comment: @Sam You can calculate sign of the product separately; then multiply `abs(a)` and `abs(b)` using your algorithm. (Pay attention to misleading `(b & '\x01' == 1)` as others suggested.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the binary code of integer, especially, the negative integer. Because the negative number has a sign bit at the beginning of the binary code to indicate the integer is negative or positive. The machine typically record an integer in complement, this makes the negative integer can have a lot of '1' at the beginning of the binary code, that makes your solution overflow.

Below is a working example.

```
int a, b, c;
a = -35;
b = 19;
c = 0;
printf("b & 01 = %d, %d, a*b: %d\n", (b & '\x01'), '\x01', a*b);

bool negative = false;
if (a < 0) {
    negative = !negative;
    a = -a;
}
if (b < 0) {
    negative = !negative;
    b = -b;
}

while (b) {
    if (b & 0x01) {
        c += a;
    }
    a <<= 1;
    b >>= 1;
    printf("a: %d, b: %d, c: %d\n", a, b, c);
}
if (negative) {
    c = -c;
}
printf("result: %d\n", c);
```

The output is:

```
a: 70, b: 9, c: 35
a: 140, b: 4, c: 105
a: 280, b: 2, c: 105
a: 560, b: 1, c: 105
a: 1120, b: 0, c: 665
result: -665
```

Comment: No, it does not work at the INT_MIN, which has reached the boundary, the max integer is 2147483657, 0x7FFFFFFF. We need to use 64 bits system for this huge number.

Comment: In C, shifting right with >> operator means differently for signed int than for unsigned int.  In case of signed int, you'll get the most significant bit copied right to the most significant bit of the value.  The code in the question doesn't get to finish, as it's comparing b with 0, which will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a binary shift to a negative value, the sign is normally copied into the most significant bit, making it the same as dividing by two a negative number.... so if you use `-19` (`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 1101`) and shift right one bit, you'll get (`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 0110`) `-10`, and you'll finish on -1 (`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`) which will never be `== 0`.

You can convert both numbers to positive and take the result sign apart before doing multiplication.  I think you can do the following.  If b < 0, then change sign to both numbers, else do the multiplication as you did.

```
if (b < 0) {
    b = -b; a = -a;
}
```

This is different if you use `unsigned int` type.  In that case, when you shift right, a 0 is inserted on the left of the value.  But you'll get a very different result in that case.